# Transferred money to the correct IBAN; however, probably specified an incorrect SWIFT code and the message not included in the receipt

Tags: international-transfer, iban, swift

I have transferred a serious amount of money to a French bank from another country. I correctly specified the IBAN number. Additionally, the bank's SWIFT (BIC) code to which I should have transferred the money was as follows:

TRPUFRP1

However, the responsible bank officer I was in contact with transferred the money to

TRPUFRP1XXX

I googled it later and I've learnt that they are both called "Tresor Public". I have also read that "XXX" at the end of the bank's name specifies its branch code. But I am not quite sure whether the bank's officer's adding "XXX" at the end of the name would cause any issue or not. He could not see the name "TRPUFRP1" as an option; therefore, he has chosen "TRPUFRP1XXX" instead.

It's been five working days since I sent the money. I have been informed that the bank in my country sent the money. I have been told that when the French bank and the French organisation which I am affiliated with will receive the money, I'll be sent a validation e-mail. However, I have not received the validation e-mail yet.

Additionally, I sent the money with a message stating my name and the name of the organisation I mentioned above. But in the receipt I received from the bank in my country, I cannot see such a message.

What should I do? Is it possible that the problem arises from the ambiguity about the SWIFT code? There are only a few days left for the deadline for the payment. When I had contacted the organisation four days ago, I was told to wait a bit longer. However, as I said, I have not received a return from them, although several days have since passed.

Comment: IBAN is unique and you shouldn't have any problem for getting it clear. From my experience, international money transferred through banks is a pain in the ass. A local clearing P2P money transfer service is always recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing 'XXX' is quite normal. The length of SWIFT/BIC codes is typically filled to the full length by X, if the bank uses no subcodes for their various locations.

if there is an issue, it shouldn't be because of that. I would guess that the receiver is not in a hurry to inform you, or something else was incorrect. Check also for Holidays in potential intermediate countries on the route, or in 'other country' - for example, India has currently Holi, which means nothing is going to happen for two days.